# Writing a string to hex convertor

Tags: c, string, hex

I tried writing a string to hex converter and was successful in the conversion

```
input : abcde
```

But the output is a string type

```
Output : "6162636465"
```

I need the converted value to be in the following form :

```
uint8_t in[] = { 0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65}
```

How do I switch it from a string to a uint8

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    unsigned char str[100],strH[200];
    int i,j;
    strcpy(str, argv[1]);
    //printf("Enter string: ");
    //scanf("%[^\n]s",str);

    printf("\nString is: %s\n",str);

    /*set strH with nulls*/
    memset(strH,0,sizeof(strH));

    /*converting str character into Hex and adding into strH*/
    for(i=0,j=0;i<strlen(str);i++,j+=2)
    {
        sprintf((char*)strH+j,"%02X",str[i]);
    }
    strH[j]='\0'; /*adding NULL in the end*/

    printf("Hexadecimal converted string is: \n");
    printf("%s\n",strH);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A hex representation makes only sense in string form. What do you really want? You want to get a `uint8_t` array of 4 from the string `"6162636465"`?

Comment: Yes, as I am using it to do bitwise operations.

Comment: After the `strcpy(str, argv[1])`, the contents of `str` are as you requested.

Comment: FYI, you can use raw char to do bitwise operation.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to store the bytes:

> ```
> 0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65
> ```

In your array of `uint8_t` from `abcde`, you are not preforming any type of hex conversion, you are simply storing the ASCII values for `a, b, c, d, e` in your array. If that is you goal, you can do it simply by assigning the value of each character to your array, e.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input, %s <hexval>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    char *s = argv[1];
    size_t i = 0, 
        len = strlen (s);
    uint8_t bytes[len];

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        bytes[i] = s[i];       /* simply store the ASCII value of each char */

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        printf (" 0x%02" PRIx8, bytes[i]);
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

(above the `uint8_t bytes[]` array contains the ASCII values for your input)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strtoasciibytes abcde
 0x61 0x62 0x63 0x64 0x65
```

If you need to validate and convert the characters to their *"hex"* values, then you can simply convert the digits to lowercase and for `0-9`, just assign `s[i] - '0'` and for `a-f` store `s[i] - 'a' + 10`. If the character doesn't fit either of those ranges after a conversion to lowercase, then it is not a hex character. (and note a byte can be comprised of 2-characters)

Let me know if that is what you were attempting or whether you actually need to convert each single character to its hex as opposed to ASCII value.

Comment: Agreed, who speaks `'W'` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your string with the hex representation is always of the same
length and that you have padding zeros:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

uint8_t hexchar_to_dec(char x)
{
    if(x >= '0' && x <= '9')
        return x - '0';

    x = tolower(x);

    if(x >= 'a' && x <= 'f')
        return 10 + x - 'a';

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{

    char hex[] = "6162636465";
    char *tmp_hex = NULL;

    uint8_t *in;

    size_t hexlen = strlen(hex);

    size_t in_size = hexlen / 2;

    // the padding zero is missing, adding at the
    // beginning
    if(hexlen % 2)
    {
        tmp_hex = calloc(hexlen + 2, 1);
        if(tmp_hex == NULL)
            return 1;
        *tmp_hex = '0';
        strcat(tmp_hex, hex);
        in_size++;
    } else
        tmp_hex = hex;



    in = calloc(in_size, sizeof *in);
    if(in == NULL)
    {
        if(tmp_hex != hex)
            free(tmp_hex);
        return 1;
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < hexlen; i = i+2)
        in[i/2] = 16*hexchar_to_dec(tmp_hex[i]) + hexchar_to_dec(tmp_hex[i+1]);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < in_size; ++i)
        printf("in[%lu] = 0x%02x\n", i, in[i]);

    free(in);
    if(tmp_hex != hex)
        free(tmp_hex);

    return 0;
}
```

Here I'm using the fact that for `'1' == '0' + 1` because of the ASCII code. My
code also takes into account when the hex string is missing a padding 0.

Output:

```
in[0] = 0x61
in[1] = 0x62
in[2] = 0x63
in[3] = 0x64
in[4] = 0x65
```

**edit**

Another way would be using `strtoul` and `memcpy`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

uint8_t hexchar_to_dec(char x)
{
    if(x >= '0' && x <= '9')
        return x - '0';

    x = tolower(x);

    if(x >= 'a' && x <= 'f')
        return 10 + x - 'a';

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{

    char hex[] = "6162636465";

    uint8_t *in;

    size_t hexlen = strlen(hex);

    size_t in_size = hexlen / 2;

    // the padding zero is missing, adding at the
    // beginning
    if(hexlen % 2)
        in_size++;

    if(sizeof(unsigned long int) < (in_size * sizeof *in))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Hex value too large for unsigned long int. Aborting\n");
        return 1;
    }

    in = calloc(in_size, sizeof *in);
    if(in == NULL)
        return 1;


    unsigned long int val = strtoul(hex, NULL, 16);
    memcpy(in, &val, in_size * sizeof *in);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < in_size; ++i)
        printf("in[%lu] = 0x%02x\n", i, in[i]);

    free(in);

    return 0;
}
```

The downside of this is that the order of the bytes in `in` would depend on the
endianness. In my computer I get

```
in[0] = 0x65
in[1] = 0x64
in[2] = 0x63
in[3] = 0x62
in[4] = 0x61
```

**edit**

I've added this check

```
    if(sizeof(unsigned long int) < (in_size * sizeof *in))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Hex value too large for unsigned long int. Aborting\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

as user chux pointed out in the comments, the `memcpy` call would overflow if
the size of the `unsigned long int` is smaller than the number of bytes
allocated for `in`.

Comment: `memcpy(in, &val, in_size * sizeof *in);` is a problem if `unsigned long val` is 4 bytes.  Suggest `uint64_t` to show your endian point.

Comment: But val is `unsigned long int` which is longer than 4 bytes. I guess you only would get in trouble if `in_size` is longer than `unsigned long int`. Or am I wrong?

Comment: C does not specify that `unsigned long int` is longer than 4 bytes.  Many systems have 4-byte `unsigned long int`, some use 8.  It is implementation dependent as long at it at least encodes values 0 to 4294967295.

Comment: @chux thanks for explanation. So it would be better to check that `unsigned long int` is at least as large as `in_size` and abort if that's not the case?

Comment: Perhaps, various ways to cope with that.

Comment: @chux thanks for the feedback, I've updated my answer.